# Error: 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals' when using Matlab .NET builder

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I am using matlab NE builder to compile a dll file which I call from C#. The matlab code is confirmed to work in matlab, but when called from c# the following error occurs:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   MWArray.dll
>
> Additional information:
>
> ... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ...  Subscript indices must either
>   be real positive integers or logicals. Error in => KalmanFilter.m at
>   line 108.

The line in question is the following:

```
plot(data(:, 1), data(:, 2));
```

I have confirmed that when the line is reached, the variable data has size n by 4, with n > 50, why the statement is supposed to make sense.

Anyone got any experience on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post more code

Comment: Just before the line that causes problems I added the line
'save debugdata data'
After inspecting the variable data prom the saved file, I can conclude that everything is in order, and running the line in matlab with the data loaded from the file works fine.

Comment: As far as I know, this issue arise when you name variables as you function names or as MatLAB functions (reserved names). Make sure this is not happening.

Comment: @noobob , that is actually exactly what had happened. If I saved and examined the whole workspace, there were a variable present called plot. How this found it's way there is somewhat of a mystery since the code still runs well in matlab. Anyhow, thank you for your input!

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this issue arise when you name variables as you function names or as MatLAB functions (reserved names).
Make sure this is not happening.

Comment: that is actually exactly what had happened. If I saved and examined the whole workspace, there were a variable present called plot. How this found it's way there is somewhat of a mystery since the code still runs well in matlab. Anyhow, thank you for your input!